# How can I run flutter web app without internet connection

Tags: flutter, apache, dart, xampp, flutter-web

I created a **flutter web** application,
and I finished building it with the command ..
`flutter build web --release` ,
and then transferred it to a local server ,
The site does not work unless it is connected to the Internet ,

I want the site to work without an internet connection ,
As I work in an organization and some users do not have internet permissions .

Please, I want a solution to this problem .

**Thanks**

Comment: What kind of errors can you see in your console when loading the Website from your local server ?

Comment: There are no errors ,  just a blank white screen , and when connected to the Internet The site works

Comment: Is your app served from a secure (HTTPS) domain?

Comment: no , Is app served from a unsecure (HTTP)

Comment: Service worker doesn't work without https.

Comment: How do I convert to HTTPS?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, that flutter has some dependencies, that can not be resolved when you, as the client, are offline. Mostly consisting of `canvaskit` and certain google fonts.

There are multiple solutions for that. The easiest being to use the html web-renderer:

```bash
flutter build web --release --web-renderer html
```

this should work for most applications, however it has lower performance than `canvaskit`, especially with high widget density.

Therefore you can also use `canvaskit` locally as it is automatically built when you build your release. But you have to set it as base url, by adding the following lines in your index.html:

```html
<script>
  window.flutterConfiguration = {
      canvasKitBaseUrl: "/canvaskit/"
  };
</script>
```

This makes sure your flutter application uses the local source for `canvaskit`. However, another problem could be the usage of google fonts, e.g. Roboto, as those often need to be downloaded as well. But you can just add those to the `pubspec.yaml` explicitly to account for that, like explained [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts).

Some sources for more informations:

[flutter web-renderers](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/renderers)

[The same issue but on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78235)

[Making Flutter offline capable](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60069)

Answer (score 2):

1. Download and set locally from asset policy for your web application
2. Add link to local Canvaskit as bellow :

> flutter build web --web-renderer=canvaskit
> --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=/canvaskit/

Answer (score 0):

To make it work for a dev build, I incorporated Spanching's answer above in the following steps.

1. Run: `flutter clean` to clean up all build cache (this is important to have canvas kit re-downloaded in step 4 below).
2. Run: `flutter pub get` to download packages per pubspec.yaml
3. If you're using build runner: `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

At this stage you should have a clean `/build` folder (I also have an ios sub-folder as I'm also developing for iOS)

4. Run: `flutter build web`

At this stage you should have a clean `/build/web` added with a `canvaskit` folder underneath it. Full path: `/build/web/canvaskit/`

Then:

5. Open `index.html` under `/web` (note - do *not* open the one under `/build/web`)
6. Add the script mentioned in the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73194206/5225270) to the body of the html file. I just added it above the existing script that's already there.
7. Run your project in deubg mode (with Wifi turned off).